# How to hash using ripemd128 on iOS / OS X?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, cryptography

I would like to hash a string using ripemd128 on iOS / OS X, but there does not seem to be core support for this, or any simple open source framework implementing it. Anyone has a solution?

Comment: This is very close to being off topic (asking for a complete solution or library/resource). But it is rather useful and already answered, so hopefully we can keep it open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If RIPEMD is not natively supported by the iOS SDK you can use an external library:

- [crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) For the integration with iOS you can see [this page](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/IOS_%28Xcode%29).
- [sphlib](http://www.saphir2.com/sphlib/) is a library implementing standard digest algorithms. It is written in ANSI C and should be compatible with iOS.